# C# - System.Net Socket.Listen Backlog only one connection issue

Tags: c#, sockets, .net-2.0, winsock

I've a problem with the backlog parameter from socket.listen.

```
System.Net.IPEndPoint ep = new System.Net.IPEndPoint(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, 556);
Socket server = new Socket(ep.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
server.Bind(ep);
server.Listen(0);
server.BeginAccept(_serverConnectionCallback, server);
```

After connect with a telnet client to localhost:556, the `_serverConnectionCallback` handled the conenction incomming.. so far, so good. 
But, if a connection (second connection) is made again with another telnet:556, this connectin is handeld in the backlog queue. 
The next connections will drop.

I want the second connection to be dropped.
Is there a bug in my code? Or a mistake in Winsock?

NetFramework 2.0

Regards Henrik

Comment: Why are you passing `0` to `Listen()`? [The documenation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.listen?view=netframework-4.7.2) states the value represents "The maximum length of the pending connections queue." Change the `0` to something appropriate for your situation.

Comment: Testet with ``-1`` as parameter, this is unlimited (system length) queue length.
``0`` is not mean maximum, shown on my post. ``0`` and ``1`` make the same issue. The second connection will queued.

Comment: I cannot found on your posted docuemntation, that ``0`` means maximum.

Comment: The value you pass to `Listen()` is the maximum. You're passing `0`, so `0` is the maximum. Change it to `5`. Now `5` is the maximum. Where did you get that `-1` is unlimited? Where does the documentation state that?

Comment: Can you test it with .net 2.0? And you can see, ``0`` and ``1`` make the same. ``-1`` is the maximum.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, it seems the minimum backlog is 1.

Comment: @itsme86 I want to have the BACKLOG with a length of 0! No other connections should be kept in the connection queue.

Comment: @TonyEdgecombe Did you find anything in the documentation. It looks like 1 is the minimum.
My solution is, I process the second connection by dropping it. :)

Comment: 1 does seem to be the minimum. In my case I closed the listening socket as soon as the callback in BeginAccept is called then open a new one after the child socket has completed its work.

Comment: @TonyEdgecombe thanks for this solution. This is mutch better than my solution.